# "I would dare say that" or "I would dare to say that" ?

Tags: grammaticality

http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/i+would+dare+to.html

I would dare say that in addressing the themes ....

I would dare to say that it is consensual. ....

I guess both of the phrases " I would dare say that..." and " I would dare to say that..." are correct and there is no difference between them. am I right or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, "dare" and "dare to" mean the same:

> Who would dare to claim that we can pay for the earth?

That could equally well be expressed as:

> Who would dare claim that we can pay for the earth?

Often, "I would dare say" means the same as "I would dare to say", but not always.

One of the examples on the page you linked to is:

> At the moment nobody would dare say that Russian industry has started climbing up from the bottom.

This could equally well be expressed as:

> At the moment nobody would dare to say that Russian industry has started climbing up from the bottom.

However, in some cases "dare say" (sometimes written "daresay") is an idiom meaning "think"/"agree" (see [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/daresay)).

Where you read this:

> There are lots of economists, I would dare say most, who would say that the best stimulus for an economy is to invest in people, people who actually need the money.

The meaning is actually:

> There are lots of economists, probably most, who would say that the best stimulus for an economy is to invest in people, people who actually need the money.